# ArrayList with Scanner not Working Properly

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java.util.scanner

This code is supposed to store Integers in the `ArrayList` and exit when the number 42 is entered, but it is not working. Sometimes the loop does not stop when 42 is supplied and sometimes it does not store all the numbers entered prior to 42.

```
import java.util.*;
class test{    
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.nextInt() != 42){
            ar.add(sc.nextInt());
        }    
        for(int i : ar){
            System.out.println(i);    
        }    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\pj\Desktop\j2\new>java test
1
2
3
5
42
2
5
```

Comment: It's always better (for me) to store the `nextSomething` into an object before processing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(sc.nextInt() != 42){
    ar.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

You are reading two ints in each iteration, so it's possible you are reading the 42 inside the loop, and therefore you don't stop when you read it.

Try to change it to :

```
int i = 0;
while((i = sc.nextInt()) != 42){
    ar.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank You , Is there any other way I can accomplish the task ? I do not see other way out.

Comment: @PankajKushwaha Did you try the code I suggested at the end of my answer?

Comment: Thank You very much sir, I see the code now. Updated and it working.I do not have enough credits to upvote :(

Comment: @PankajKushwaha You're welcome. And you can always accept the answer by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

These three lines cause the problem; you are asking user input twice

```
while(sc.nextInt() != 42){
    ar.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

You should store the value to a variable, like this

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
while (n != 42) {
    ar.add(n);
    n = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Hopefully that helps :)